# Specs2 - Mock objects inside method

Tags: scala, mocking, playframework-2.0, specs2

I'm writting unit tests and i would like to know if it's possible to mock an object that is instanced inside the method that i'm testing.

Here is an example of a method that i would like to test:

```
def sendMessageToBroker(message:Message) = {

  val soapBody = xmlBody("user", "pass", message.identifier, 
      message.to, message.message)

  val response = new WebServiceUtil().doPost("uri", soapBody.toString(),
  "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "action")

  response
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
when call doPost, return new Response(200, 'Success')
```

Is it possible?

I've tried do it using spy() and mock, but no sucess:

```
val ws = new WebServiceUtil

val spiedObj = spy(ws)
spiedObj.doPost("uri", xml,
  "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
  "action") returns new Response(200, "Success")

val xx = messageService.sendMessageToBroker(new Message())
```

Any ideas on how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
val webService = mock[WebServiceUtil]

webService.doPost("uri", xml, "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "action") returns 
   new Response(200, "Success")

// pass the mock webservice as an argument
sendMessageToBroker(new Message, webService)
```

The important part is that you need to be able to pass a mock `WebServiceUtil` to your method being tested! There are many ways to do that. The simplest one is to pass the instance to a constructor method of our "class under test":

```
class MyClass(webService: WebServiceUtil) {
  def sendMessageToBroker(message: Message) = {
    // use the webservice
  }
}
```

A more involved method would use Guice and the `Inject` annotation to pass the service (especially since you tagged the question as a `play-framework-2.0` one). You will be interested in following [this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159857/specs2-how-to-test-a-class-with-more-than-one-injected-dependency/) then.